# Can my iPad open iPhone apps using the iPhone 5 form factor?

Tags: ipad, universal-binaries

At the moment, my iPhone apps(for example: Yahoo Weather) on my iPad 3 Retina running iOS 7.0(11A465) are displayed using the 3.5" iPhone screen in the iPad, is it possible for me to change it to display the 4" iPhone screen(iPhone 5) in the iPad?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, the more information you give the better opportunity you give someone a chance to give you an answer. I.e what model iPad, what iOs version, names of  specific apps.

Comment: I've edited the question to include hardware and iOS version.

Comment: Yahoo weather is universal. So should display at the native Rez. Of the iPad I.e full screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible. iPhone apps running on the iPad will use the smaller iPhone 4s screen's aspect ratio.

Comment: I thought so too, I looked for Apple's official documentation on this but I could not find it. I guess that's just the way it is.